# How can I convert my iterative function to a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

I want to turn my function into a recursive function because I think it will have a cleaner look to it, but I am not sure how to go about it.

```
void perm_rec_1(int N, int nr_vals){
  int arr[N];
  int i=0;
  while(i <  N)
  {
    arr[i] = 0;
    i++;
  }
  int k=0;
  do {
    int z=0;
    while(z < N) {
      printf("%d ",arr[z]);
      z++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    k = N - 1;
    while (k >= 0) {
      arr[k]++;
      if (arr[k] < nr_vals) {
        break;
      }
      arr[k] = 0;
      k--;
    }
  } while (k >= 0);
}
```

Comment: If your motivation is a "cleaner" look, you should do several things before you consider recursion. First, use meaningful variable names, not one-letter ones. Secondly, split this up into different functions with meaningful names. Thirdly, use proper formatting/indentation. Lastly, add comments and signature documentation. By the time you've done all of this, it will be much much easier to try to figure out howto convert it to recursion.

Comment: An additional note, if you don't know how to go about making it recursive then there little evidence that it will actually improve anything. I will still see what I can do for you

Comment: yea that is my problem, i am not good at making a recursive function and I will appreciate it @jcolemang

Comment: I would generally prefer a loop over recursion.  My mind takes the same burden the computer does of a recursion: having to remember the entire stack. The only times I remember I've used recursion have been for walking through a tree: on each leaf, iterate over all leaves and recurse onto them.

Comment: I prefer that as well but, the teachers usually emphasis the topic of recusrsion so I assume  its going to be something we really need once we get out of the school and start working for companies. I try to convert every program I do it recursion,even though I don't have to, so I can get better at because I know its something im weak at.

Answer (score 2):

First, if all you want is a cleaner look you may want to do something like this:

```
/*
 * prints all numbers in base base
 * will a number of digits up to num_digits
 */
void perm_rec_1(int num_digits, int base) {

  // create an array of size num_digits, initialize to 0
  int arr[num_digits];
  int i=0;
  while(i <  num_digits) {
    arr[i] = 0;
    i++;
  }

  int current_digit=0;
  do {

    // print everything in arr on one line
    int i=0;
    while(i < num_digits) {
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // reset the current digit to the rightmost digit
    current_digit = num_digits - 1;
    while (current_digit >= 0) {

      // increment the current digit
      arr[current_digit]++;

      // if the current digit is less than the base
      // go to the top of the loop (print the line)
      if (arr[current_digit] < base) {
        break;
      }

      // else reset the digit and shift it over one
      arr[current_digit] = 0;
      current_digit--;

    } // end while
  } while (current_digit >= 0); // end 'do'
}
```

Instead of rewriting it entirely, think of some more useful variable names. One of the most time consuming parts of answering this question was figuring our what it was trying to do. If you can avoid it, never use single character variable names. Think of something that actually reflects what the variable is being used for. Comments are good too, but good variable names are better.

---

Now, to actually answer your question. Here is the recursive version of the same program:

```
void print_arr(int len, int* arr) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}


void perm_rec_1_helper(int num_digits, int base, int curr_digit, int* arr) {

  if (num_digits == curr_digit) {
    print_arr(num_digits, arr);
    return;
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < base; i++) {
    arr[curr_digit] = i;
    perm_rec_1_helper(num_digits, base, curr_digit+1, arr);
  }

}


void perm_rec_1(int num_digits, int base) {
  int arr[num_digits];
  perm_rec_1_helper(num_digits, base, 0, arr);
}
```

See if you can work through the code to understand it. If you cannot, I will add some explanation to my answer.

Comment: The function calls to `print_all_digits_helper()` should be renamed to `perm_rec_1_helper()`, or vice versa.

Comment: @DavidBowling whoops, forgot to rename those. Thanks

Comment: Thanks after reading through your code its getting a bit more clearer to me on what I need to do

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the others who have indicated that it would be best to first work on making the version with loops better. Improving names and breaking tasks into functions can help a lot with the clarity of your code. Here is a version that uses loops. I have tried to break the task up into smaller functions to aid in readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void show_perms(size_t arr_sz, size_t nr_vals);
void print_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz]);
bool next_array(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals);

int main(void)
{
    size_t nr_vals;
    size_t arr_sz;

    printf("Enter number of values: ");
    scanf("%zu", &nr_vals);
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%zu", &arr_sz);

    show_perms(arr_sz, nr_vals);

    return 0;
}

void show_perms(size_t arr_sz, size_t nr_vals)
{
    int arr[arr_sz];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;

    do{
        print_perm(arr_sz, arr);
    } while (next_array(arr_sz, arr, nr_vals));
}

void print_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

bool next_array(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals)
{
    int i;

    for (i = (arr_sz - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = (arr[i] + 1) % nr_vals;
        if (arr[i] != 0)
            break;
    }

    if (i < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

I wrote the above version first, and used it as a guide in constructing this recursive solution. At first I had a boolean function `finished()` that checked to see if the current permutation was the final one, but then I realized that changing the `index` variable from `size_t` to `int` allows `index` to hold a value of -1 after the final permutation is found. This simplified the recursive code, and made me look at the loop solution again, which also had a test function called `is_another()`. I removed this function and changed the `next_array()` function to return `true` if there are more permutations, and `false` if not (when `i` is negative).

The recursive solution uses two mutually recursive functions to build and print the permutations. The function `print_permutations()` gets things started by declaring an array and zeroing it out. Then the `print_perm()` function is called, first printing the first permutation (all zeroes), and then calling the `next_perm()` function. This function recursively calls itself until the next permutation is found, at which point `print_perm()` is called again, and everything starts over. This continues until the value of `index` reaches -1, at which point the last call to `next_perm()` returns.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_permutations(size_t arr_sz, size_t nr_vals);
void print_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals);
void next_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals, int index);

int main(void)
{
    size_t nr_vals;
    size_t arr_sz;

    printf("Enter number of values: ");
    scanf("%zu", &nr_vals);
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%zu", &arr_sz);

    print_permutations(arr_sz, nr_vals);

    return 0;
}

void print_permutations(size_t arr_sz, size_t nr_vals)
{
    int arr[arr_sz];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;

    print_perm(arr_sz, arr, nr_vals);
}

void print_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    next_perm(arr_sz, arr, nr_vals, (arr_sz - 1));
}

void next_perm(size_t arr_sz, int arr[arr_sz], size_t nr_vals, int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return ;

    arr[index] = (arr[index] + 1) % nr_vals;
    if (arr[index] != 0)
        print_perm(arr_sz, arr, nr_vals);
    else
        next_perm(arr_sz, arr, nr_vals, (index - 1));
}
```

Here is the output from a sample run:

```
Enter number of values: 2
Enter size of array: 3
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0 
0 1 1 
1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 1 0 
1 1 1
```